# How to scale a Kinect Skeleton to match to other Kinect Skeleton

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

I have some saved skeleton data, the data corresponds to my own skeleton proportion, lets call this skeleton Sk1.
And i have other skeleton data (that corresponds to a ten old year child, by example). lets call this Sk2.

**I want to scale one skeleton size, to another skeleton size, mantaining the proportions.**

PS: I know the ScaleTo() extension method os Coding4Fun library but i dont understand this method in deeply.

How can i achieve it?

**EDIT 1**
Tha ScaleTo() extension method from the Coding4Fun did not work for me.
So i am trying to implement my ow scale method to scale the entire skeleton, please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596331/kinect-skeleton-scaling-strange-behaviour) for the actual code

Comment: This is tricky to test, as I lack access to a 10-year old.  I think `ScaleTo()` will do what you want though.  Taking both skeletons and applying the `ScaleTo()` function with the same `width` & `height` should produce two skeletons that are close to the same size (maybe some slight differences).  Try just scaling each of the `Joints` for both skeletons to the same `width` and `height` and see what happens.  I'm without a small child to verify my thinking is correct.

Comment: Seems to work. I a wondering abut scaleTo() too.

Comment: What are you wondering about it?

Comment: To use ScaleTo, like you described, but i dont tryed it yet.

Comment: hey @Evil Closet Monkey, i tryed the ScaleTo but it did not work as expected for me, have you tryed it? look at the edits, i am tryin to implement my own method.

Comment: I've not had a chance to play with this yet.  Hopefully this weekend.