# Where can I get BoneOrientation.StartJoint in kinect v2

Tags: kinect, kinect-v2

I'm trying to scale a skeleton with Kinect SDK v2 and found this nice code example (at the bottom of the thread):
[Kinect skeleton Scaling strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596331/kinect-skeleton-scaling-strange-behaviour)

The problem is that the example is done in earlier versions and it looks like a lot has changed in the SDK since then.

I'm trying to figure out how I can get the BoneOrientation.StartJoint and BoneOrientation.EndJoint in the v2 SDK. Looks like Microsoft has replaced BoneOrienation with JointOrientation and that structure does, of course, not containing any startJoint nor endJoint.

Can I get this information by myself from somewhere in the sdk or do I have to connect the skeleton manually by defining the connection of the joints?

Answer (score 0):

There are no bone structures in KINECT v2, instead [this documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn799273.aspx) states that

> Joint hierarchy flows from the center of the body to the extremities, and from the top-most to the bottom-most joints. These connections are described as bones.

The documentation for [`JointType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.jointtype.aspx) describes the connectivity of the various joints and also the diagram included below. Use [`IBody::GetJoints`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.kinect.ibody.getjoints.aspx) to obtain the dictionary of joints (each one provides its spatial position). After that it is up to you to navigate the joints. For scaling of the skeleton, you should be able to scale each joint position without prior knowledge of how they connect to each other.

[image]